# What's the Hölder distance between any two distinct brownian motion paths?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-path-theory

We define the $\alpha$-Hölder semi-norm as
$$\| X\|_\alpha = \sup_{s\neq t \in [0,T]} \frac{|X_{s} - X_t|}{|s-t|^\alpha}$$
and the distance function between two rough paths as,
$$\rho_{\alpha}(\mathbf{X}, \tilde{\mathbf{X}}) = \| X - \tilde{X}\|_\alpha + \| \mathbb{X} - \tilde{\mathbb{X}} \|_{2\alpha},$$
where $\mathbb{X}$ is the enhanced path.

Denoting $\mathbf{B}^\text{ito}$ as the enhanced Brownian motion with respect to the Ito integration, i.e. we denote with $B_\cdot(\omega)$ a brownian motion, whose path is determined by a paramter $\omega$, then
$$ \mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_{s}(\omega) = \left(B_s(\omega), \mathbb{B}^{\text{ito}}_{s} := \int_0^s B_{r}(\omega) dB_r(\omega)\right).$$

Then, given two distinct paths $\mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_{s}(\omega)$ and $\mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_{s}(\tilde{\omega})$ for $\omega \neq \tilde{\omega}$, what is a good upper bound for
$$\rho_{\alpha}(\mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_{s}(\omega), \mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_{s}(\tilde{\omega})) \le ?$$

My issue is that any estimate I can think of are in probability. So, at best I can think of taking $\omega$ such that it maximizes the path and $\tilde{\omega}$ which minimizes the path, so to have the largest increments. But even in that case we'd have something that doesn't seem bounded (at least it is almost surely, but not for any path, right?) or am I wrong? Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Is this an exercise? I am assuming that by $\omega$ you mean a realization?  I suppose  to capture the idea of *distinct paths* you could try taking independent copies of $B^{ito}$ and trying to compute their distance.

Comment: Yep, if we take different paths/realizations. Ok, so the trivial bound is given by $\| \mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_1 \|_{\alpha, 2\alpha} + \| \mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_2 \|_{\alpha, 2\alpha}$ which is finite for $1/3 \le \alpha < 1/2$ under the assumption that $\mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_1, \mathbf{B}^{\text{ito}}_2$ are independent and $\| (\cdot, \ast) \|_{\alpha, 2\alpha} = \| \cdot\|_\alpha + \|\ast\|_{2\alpha}$, right? Is there anything better in your opinion?

Comment: If you are looking for envelope/support-theorem type results then for Brownian motion we have the iterated law of logarithm or Stroock-Varadhan support theorem. Similarly for the rough path lifts, you can try to get envelope estimates or "support theorems" see Friz-Victoir.